# Is it possible to find nodes containing a "simple list" using xpath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath

is it possible to write an xpath 1.0 expression that finds for a given node all its direct child nodes that have one or more child nodes again, where all this child nodes have the same name and they do not have child nodes again?

Example:

```
<root>
  <`mynode`>
    <findthis>
      <entry>a</entry>
      <entry>b</entry>
      <entry>c</entry>
    </findthis>
    <ignorethis>
      <foo>a</foo>
      <bar>b</bar>
    </ignorethis>
    <ignorethat>
      <child>
        <childofchild></childofchild>
      </child>
    </ignorethat>
  <mynode>
</root>
```

For `mynode`, the xpath expression should find node `findthis`, but not `ignorethis` (because child nodes have different names), and not `ignorethat` (because its child node has a child again).
I could of course do this programmatically in multiple steps (Perl with `XML::LibXML`), but I am curious if I can do this with a single xpath.

Searched via google but did not find i solution.

Comment: XPath 2 can do it with e.g.  `root/mynode/*[*[not(*)] and count(distinct-values(*/node-name())) eq 1]`, I am struggling to find something in XPath 1.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like

```
root/mynode/*[
  *[not(*)] and 
  not(*[position()>1 and name(.) != name(preceding-sibling::*[1])])]
```

Comment: I tried it and it works well! I'll use it in my app since it simplifies my code! Thanks again!